# &amp; is displayed in some titles in 'settings' windows

Tags: 16.04, gnome, settings, ubuntu-gnome, 17.04

At some point `&amp;` is not properly displayed as `&` in some system menus. How this can be cured. Ubuntu Gnome [Screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zB8C.png) (look at window title).

Comment: Your question is tagged 16.04 and 17.04. Which do you have?

Comment: Have you already tried restarting?

Comment: I've found the reason why it was broken and commented the solution below. After restart my solution is legit.

Answer (score 0):

So the reason for that "broken" names was the fact the names were messed up in following way:
e.g.: `Mouse &amp; Touch­pad` was stored as this: `Mouse &amp;amp; Touch­pad` which visually represents `Mouse &amp; Touch­pad`.

Solution: manually edit names and remove `amp;` part with help of menu editor.